# Javascript onbeforeunload : How to detect if user click on "Leave this page"

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with a very annoying situation when i need to check that user is clicked on "Leave this page" and I need to redirect them to a another page using `window.location`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
           //how to check for "Leave this page"
        }
```

Thanks .

Comment: I do not think you can prevent the user leave the page! You can only alert some kind of warning...

Comment: You can add an event handler for the "unload" event too, and if you get there then you'll know that the user opted to leave the page. However, setting `window.location` in that context (probably) won't work.

Comment: Javascript onunload does not support in Chrome and In Opera : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp Jqueries unload is deprecated from 1.8

Answer (score -2):

Keep a global variable

```
var hasClickedLeave = false;
```

and put an onclick listener on the "Leave this Page" button,

so that you can change

```
hasClickedLeave = true;
```

After that, you can check:

```
if (hasClickedLeave) {
    //redirect to another page
}
```

Comment: ?? how can put onclick listener on the "Leave this Page" button it is coming under the JS dialog... :(

Comment: Are you talking about the browser "Leave this page" button?

Comment: This only works when there's interaction with something the page has control over. If the user clicks a bookmark, for example, this will have no effect.

Comment: Yes, I thought ravisoni was talking about a custom Leave this page button. In cases where interaction occurs with an element the page doesn't have control over, it won't work.